# How can I read a JSON reponse from server using DOJO?

Tags: javascript, json, dojo, struts2

I am having some trouble fetching some data from the server and populating a data store with it:

This is my script code in Display.jsp page:

```
dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {

    // our test data store for this example:
    dojo.xhrGet({
        url: "jsonAction.action",// this line can call the action in struts2. I had tested it !
        handleAs: "json",
        preventCache: true,
        load: function(response, ioArgs){
            //dojo.byId("replace").innerHTML = response;
            // I can get json data by changing handleAs:"text"
        //return response; //   
        }
    });

    var  jsonStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
        //??? how can I get the json data?
    });
```

I want to use this data latter to populate a dojox.grid.DataGrid

I am using Struts2, Hibernate, Tomcat 6

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I want to use that jsonStore to binding the data into dojox.grid.dataGrid

Comment: you can edit the question to make it complet, if you didn't know.

Comment: thank you for helping me to edit my question, the Elite Gentleman. This is the first time I post on this website

Answer (score 3):

do not use `dojo.xhrGet`. `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore` has a parameter `url` in which you can specify the data source. here's an example grid:

```
var sampleGrid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
    store: new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
        url: "JSON_source",
        clearOnClose: true,
        urlPreventCache: true
    }),
    structure: [ 
        {cells: 
            [[ 
                {field: "JSON_field", name: "displayed value"},
                ...
            ]] 
        }                   
    ],
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you h4bO. I did like your post, it can call json file from server but it isn't display anything ("Sorry, an error occurred")

Comment: And this is my json file which I tried to save :   
    {"listProductBean":[
{"id":1,"price":500,"productName":"AAAA"},
{"id":2,"price":600,"productName":"BBBB"},
{"id":3,"price":700,"productName":"CCCC"},
{"id":4,"price":800,"productName":"DDDD"},
{"id":5,"price":900,"productName":"EEEE"},
{"id":6,"price":10000,"productName":"FFFF"},
{"id":7,"price":10100,"productName":"GGGG"},
{"id":8,"price":10200,"productName":"HHHH"},
{"id":9,"price":10300,"productName":"KKKK"},
{"id":10,"price":10400,"productName":"LLLL"}]
}

Comment: where do you get this error msg? in firebug/on the page/inside grid/... ? post your grid definition.

try adding `query: {id: "*"}` to your grid definition (`query` is a parameter). you can also check `dojox.grid.DataGrid` programmatic example here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html

Comment: thank you so much....I get that error on display page. Finally, i know why that has an error. Beacause in the action file, I have getter method is : getListProductBean() . it must be getItems() method. Dojox.grid.datagrid just only read json with format as : {"Items":[{"id":1,"price":500,"productName":"AAAA"},...]}
Thank you again, h4b0, Sincerely!

Comment: my English skill is not well, so if my comment make you confuse, you would like to feel free to chat with me. Y!: caubesitinh_yourlove@yahoo.com .I'm a vietnamese.

Comment: if my answer was correct, mark it as such - that's the best way of saying 'thanks' here ; )